# Instantiate as many gameObjects as possible from one position and end at another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I instantiate as many gameObjects as possible that start at one position and end at another position. For example, instantiate gameObject at x=0 and end at x=5 axis. Between these two values, there should be as many gameObjects as possible, preferably 10-12 small scaled ones.

```
public GameObject prefab;

void Awake()
{
    GameObject ref = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Comment: Well, the `Vector3.zero` should be replaced with a variable that can be given a lerped position between 0 and 5...`ref` is also not a valid variable identifier.

Comment: please define `as many gameObjects as possible`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your answers, I did something like this:
(a) Create two gameObjects in the scene separated by some distance
(b) In the script, give reference to these two gameObjects
(c) Give number of segments (spheres) that should be generated between these two points

```
 public Transform PointA; public Transform PointB; public float NumberOfSegments = 3; public float AlongThePath = .25f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Start()
{

    Create();
}

void Create()
{
    StartCoroutine(StartSpheringOut());
}

IEnumerator StartSpheringOut()
{
    NumberOfSegments += 1;// since we are skipping 1st placement since its the same as starting point we increase the number by 1 
    AlongThePath = 1 / (NumberOfSegments);//% along the path

    for (int i = 1; i < NumberOfSegments; i++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        Vector3 CreatPosition = PointA.position + (PointB.position - PointA.position) * (AlongThePath * i);

        GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphere.transform.position = CreatPosition;
        sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f);



    }
```

Answer (score 3):

when you say `as many GameObjects as possible` I guess you mean without overlapping?

**This solution works assuming the `prefab` uses `Collider`s.**

I would instantiate the first object allways and simply get it's bounding box so we know how big it is

```
 var first = Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero + Vector3.right * MinX, Quaternion.identity);

var bounds = new Bounds(Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero);
foreach (var col in first.GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true))
{
    bounds.Encapsulate(col.bounds);
}

// now you can get the size in X direction
var width = bounds.size.x;
```

I suspect the pivot point of your prefab would probably be in the center so first move it to the right by half of its width

```
first.transform.position += Vector3.right * width / 2f;
```

Now you can check how many objects will fit in your given range. Lets say e.g. the width was `1` then in a range from `0` to `5` there would fit in total `4` objects. There will be some redundancies in the calculation (adding `1` then decreasing `1` etc ) but I'll leave it sfor better understanding

```
var minPosition = MinX;
var maxPosition = MaxX;

var actualMinPosition = minPosition + width / 2;
var actualMaxPosition = maxPosition - width / 2;

// +1 here since before we reduced actualMinPosition and actualMaxPosition by 
// exactly 1 * width
var possibleAmount = (int)Mathf.Floor((actualMaxPosition - actualMinPosition) / width) + 1;
```

So now instantiate the missing objects

```
// since I guess you also want them evenly spread between the start and end position
var distanceBetween = (actualMaxPosition - actualMinPosition) / (possibleAmount - 1);
```

// since we already instantiated the first one
        // we spawn only possibleAmount - 1 more 
        for (var i = 0; i < possibleAmount - 1; i++)
        {
            // +1 here since we started the loop with i=0 but the first
            // object here is actually the second to be spawned in total
            // so we want it to be moved already
            var x = actualMinPosition + distanceBetween * (i + 1);

```
        var obj = Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero + Vector3.right * x, Quaternion.identity);
    }
```

---

So all together

```
public void Spawn()
{
    var first = Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

    var bounds = new Bounds(Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero);
    foreach (var col in first.GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true))
    {
        bounds.Encapsulate(col.bounds);
    }

    // now you can get the size in X direction
    var width = bounds.size.x;

    first.transform.position += Vector3.right * width / 2f;


    var minPosition = MinX;
    var maxPosition = MaxX;

    var actualMinPosition = minPosition + width / 2;
    var actualMaxPosition = maxPosition - width / 2;

    // +1 here since before we reduced actualMinPosition and actualMaxPosition by 
    // exactly 1 * width
    var possibleAmount = (int)Mathf.Floor((actualMaxPosition - actualMinPosition) / width) + 1;


    // since I guess you also want them evenly spread between the start and end position
    var distanceBetween = (actualMaxPosition - actualMinPosition) / (possibleAmount - 1);

    // since we already instantiated the first one
    // we spawn only possibleAmount - 1 more 
    for (var i = 0; i < possibleAmount - 1; i++)
    {
        // +1 here since we started the loop with i=0 but the first
        // object here is actually the second to be spawned in total
        // so we want it to be moved already
        var x = actualMinPosition + distanceBetween * (i + 1);

        var obj = Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero + Vector3.right * x, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

---

[image]

*I simply destroyed and respawned everything in `Update` for this demo*

Comment: This is a great example! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could loop the amount of enemys that you want to be spawned(12 for example) and increase the position at every loop iteration.

```
public GameObject prefab;
public Vector3 pos;

void Awake()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(prefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        pos.x += 0.5f;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this definitely spawns 12 objects, it does not do so between the confines of *`x=0 and x=5`* nor does it take into account the object's size, *`there should be as many as possible`*

Comment: This worked as I wanted. Although I thought of describing Start point  (x, y, z) and End point (x, y, z) and to create as many spheres as possible between these two points.

Answer (score 1):

This should create 10 GameObject between 0 and 5.

```
void Awake() {  
     for(float x = 0; x < 5; x+=0.5f){
          Vector3 loc = new Vector3(x, 0, 0);
          GameObject gameObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, loc, Quaternion.identity);
     }
 }
```

Comment: While this will definitely spawn *an amount* of objects between the locations of x=0 and x=5, it does not spawn *as many as will fit*: *`there should be as many gameObjects as possible, preferably 10-12`*

Comment: This worked as I wanted. Although I thought of describing Start point  (x, y, z) and End point (x, y, z) and to create as many spheres as possible between these two points.